# What's the simplest way to handle mouse click events for children of a GameObject in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclick, mouseevent, parent-child

I have created an empty GameObject (named FileCabinet) and assigned 4 prefabs as children (CabinetFrame, Drawer01, Drawer02, and Drawer03).

I would like to be able to click on any of the drawers to open them, but everything that I have tried thus far returns the parent GameObject FileCabinet as the item clicked rather than any of the children.

What's the best/simplest approach to call a method when any of the drawer child objects are clicked?

**Update:**

@LoïcLeGrosFrère provided a solution that ultimately worked.  I initially had problems with events not firing because my UI was blocking raycasts to my 3D file cabinet object.  I resolved the issue by adding a Canvas Group component to my Canvas and unchecking Blocks Raycasts, but this then disabled all my UI components.  I then added Canvas Group components to individual UI panels and checked Ignore Parent Groups.  I'm not sure if this is the correct way to handle the raycast conflict but it did work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach I see is:

Add a `Physics Raycaster` component to your camera.

Add a `Event System` to your scene, with a `Input System UI Input Module`.

Then, add this script to your drawers:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Drawer : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Open {gameObject.name}.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented this and reviewed several times but I cannot get OnPointerClick to fire.  Not sure if I matters but this is a non-UI, 3D object that I'm attempting to click.  The drawer object also has a box collider component.

Comment: Apparently, my Canvas Graphic Raycaster is preventing the Drawer (which is not part of the UI) from being clicked.  If I disable the Canvas Raycaster, the clicks register.  Any thoughts on how to rectify this conflict?